# How do I see the command line equivalent of clicking Verify?

Tags: esp8266, library, compile, command-line

I am using the ESP8266 board manager. I want to see how Arduino IDE compiles my code once I click Verify.

#### Why do I want to do this?

I am trying to integrate a C library for which there is now Arduino library package available. So I have to integrate it from source. I want to be able to specify custom `-I`, `-L`  and `-l` flags when I compile my code.

Comment: Turn on the verbose compiler settings in the preferences.

Answer (score 1):

In the Arduino IDE switch on `File`>`Preferences`>`Upload erbose` and `Compile Verbose`

When you build you will see all the compiler commands

The verify is often a `-v` param in the command

You will find the esp8266 platform.txt in a location such as `c:\users\[name]\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\esp8266...`

The `platform.txt` contains all the compiler switches, the `boards.txt` in the same location can also contain board specific switches.

You can not specify different switches for different files in a compilation but you could compile your code into an archive then force it into the build process. Not sure if that is practical or not.